# Vuex: Why disable strict mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I don't see any cons to using strict mode with this `vuex`. The performances seem better and it is easier to debug. So, why disable that mode?

Comment: It physically cannot have better performance

Comment: yes, I had a wrong understanding of strict mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strict mode should not be used in production. Strict mode runs a synchronous deep watcher on the state tree for detecting inappropriate mutations, and this can slow down the application. To avoid changing strict to false each time you want to create a production bundle, you should use a build tool that makes the strict value false when creating the production bundle

you can enable that mode with this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({  // ...  strict: true});
```

Comment: Related: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html#development-vs-production